# Percent signs disappearing from verbatim block (ltxdoc class)

Tags: verbatim, characters, comments

Is the following expected:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
% why is my percent sign gone?
\relax % not here
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image: missing percent]

Comment: ltxdoc is designed for dtx files where all the document is prefixed by `%` (including verbatim sections).

Comment: sigh... I recently started writing my dtx files in a manner which avoids to have to prefix all the lines with a `%` and this is why I only now realized the gobbling up of `%` signs at the beginning of lines. Doubling it `%%` leaves a survivor, which is fine for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Class `ltxdoc` is a LaTeX class for typesetting the documentation in `.dtx` files. The class loads package `doc` that does most of the work including the definition of environment `verbatim`. In `.dtx` files the documentation lines usually starts with `%` to get ignored, when `docstrip` extracts the code. Instead of

```
\begin{verbatim}
% why is my percent sign gone?
\relax % not here
\end{verbatim}
```

the common use case is rather:

```
%\begin{verbatim}
%verbatim stuff that should be set without the
%percent signs at the start of the lines.
%\end{verbatim}
```

Therefore package `doc` modifies `verbatim` to ignore the percent sign at the start of a line. This is done by macro `\check@percent` that can be redefined locally:

```
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\let\check@percent\relax
\begin{verbatim}
% percent sign
\relax % and here
\end{verbatim}
\endgroup
```

Comment: Thanks, I had not paid attention to that redefinition of `verbatim` by `doc` until today when I converted an old `dtx` of mine to a new manner of setting up things where I still use `ltxdoc` (or `scrdoc`) but do not have to comment out the user-manual part, only the source code comments. Replacing `%` by `%%` gives me an acceptable work-around in the `verbatim` blocks and doing `\let\check@percent\relax` is still better, thanks.